# Not only global errors but all errors in Twig (Symfony2)

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I've got this in my form theme:

```
{% block form_errors %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in errors %}
                <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```

and when I call it like this:

```
form_errors(form)
```

It displays only 'global' errors for the form. How can I get in it all the form errors, even for specific fields in this one section?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> {{ form_errors(form.field) }}

to render errors of a specific field.

Comment: I know. But I don't want to remember about it every time I change the form. I want to display ALL the forms in one block. All the global ones and all the specific ones.

Comment: do a loop 
{% for error in form_errors %}
    {{ error }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: sorry its
 {% for field in form %}
    {{ form_errors(field) }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: I get the error mentioned above: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to render the form as none of the following blocks exist: "_fos_user_registration_form_save_errors", "submit_errors", "button_errors".") in FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig at line 6. "